# Saving current Python file contents without filename

Tags: python, filenames

So I need to be able to copy across the current file contents (first 20 characters) to another file without using the filename as this could be changed at any time.  How do I go about this? So far I have this code but it uses the file-name:

```
h="this a a virus!"
i="This will not be copied"
print("You Have Successfully Copied into your target file!")

infile = open ("assignment1.py", 'r')
filestr = infile.read()
appendFile = filestr[0:20]


L = list()
f = open('target.py', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    L.append(line)
L.insert(0,appendFile)
f.close()

fi = open('target.py', 'w')
for line in range(len(L)):
    fi.write(L[line])

fi.close()
```

Comment: You want to write to a file that doesn't have a name?

Comment: It is the current file I want to copy.  It is only the first 20 characters of that file (Supposedly how a virus would work) but as the file name may change I can't call it using the open (filename) method

Comment: You mean `sys.argv[0]`?

Comment: Side-note: `for line in f.readlines():` is almost always best expressed as `for line in f:`; the former slurps the whole file into an unnecessary `list` before iterating, the latter iterates as it reads. Of course, all of this code is generally anti-Pythonic (`for i in range(len(L)):` should be `for line in L:` iterating lines directly instead of iterating indices and indexing).

Comment: wait you want to copy the first 20 characters of a file to another file, and without changing what. please explain more

Answer (score 0):

U can use [listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) for folder with your files:

```
from os import listdir

files = listdir('path_to_folder')

for one_file in file:
    with open(one_file, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read(20)
    with open(one_file, 'w') as f:
        full_data = f.read() + data
        f.write(full_data)
```